# ps column width truncated in FreeBSD

Tags: zsh, freebsd, ps

`ps aux | grep mongo`

in zsh, for example, outputs

`/usr/local/bin/mongod --logpath /var/db/mongodb/mongod.log --logappend --config /usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf --dbpath /var/db/mong`

You can see that it runs off the screen and gets cutoff at the end.

In FreeBSD, how can I see the full output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-w` option (repeated if necessary). Try:

```
ps auxwww | grep mongo
```

See [the manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps) for more.

Comment: `ps auxww | grep mongo` works too!  Thank you!  I heard people say to use `-w` once or twice before, but I didn't understand that the `auxww` stuff were options.  Because typically options are preceded by a dash, but in this case they are not.  Very strange that there's no dash.